# How to change the date of travel of a Georgian railway ticket purchased online?

Tags: trains, georgia-country

How can I change the date of a return ticket (Georgian railway) from Tbilisi to Batumi, purchased online?

Comment: Where did you purchase it from? The railway company, or a travel agent?

Comment: OP has not returned to answer clarifications/questions from comments. Put on hold for now.